# How to convert tojson an object with one of field is a jsonstring

Tags: java, gson

I have an entity of:

```
class A {
    String errors ;//  a json string of some type (type could vary).
    Double value;
    ...
    public A(String theErrors, Double theValue) {
      errors = theErrors;
      value=theValue;
    }
}

A a = new A("{tl:[\"err1\"]...}", 10d);
```

I need to transform *a* to a json string.

With google [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library I could use:

```
String str = gson.toJson(a)
```

But s.a. errors field is a String, it is escaped, and the result is:

> // {"errors": **"{** tl:["err1"] ...**}"**, "value":10 }

not a

> // {"errors": **{** tl:["err1"]... **}**, "value":10 }

As for now I try something like:

```
String str = gson.toJson(a).replace("\"{", "{").replace("}\"}", "}}")
```

but that is a fragile solution.

*Does anyone know, if there is a better way to fix that? Thanks in advance.*

PS: the point is that type of underlying errors object is unknown (it depends on the source of errors)

Comment: Show us the code of the constructor `A(String, Double)`.

Comment: The problem is that in your code sample, the first argument is not valid JSON

Comment: What about if you add a `Gson errors_json;` in your class properties and before your `gson.toString();` run `a.errors_json = gson.toJson(a.errors);`.

Answer (score 0):

seems I've found a solution:

```
String getAsJson(A a) {
    JsonObject jsonMedia = (JsonObject) g.toJsonTree(a);
    jsonMedia.add("errors", g.fromJson(a.getA(), JsonElement.class));
    return g.toJson(jsonMedia);
}
```